# Troubleshooting Windows freeze with NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080

Tags: windows-10, freeze, hardware-failure

My Windows 10 Pro x64 crashes randomly. T̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶r̶a̶s̶h̶ ̶m̶a̶n̶i̶f̶e̶s̶t̶s̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶l̶e̶t̶e̶ ̶f̶r̶e̶e̶z̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶u̶t̶e̶r̶.̶ ̶T̶h̶e̶ ̶h̶u̶m̶a̶n̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶f̶a̶c̶e̶ ̶d̶e̶v̶i̶c̶e̶s̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶r̶i̶e̶f̶ ̶p̶o̶w̶e̶r̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶t̶o̶n̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶m̶o̶v̶e̶s̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶c̶r̶e̶e̶n̶.̶ ̶H̶o̶w̶e̶v̶e̶r̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶i̶m̶a̶g̶e̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶ ̶r̶e̶m̶a̶i̶n̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶c̶r̶e̶e̶n̶.̶
The crash manifests as a complete freezing of the computer for some duration, such as 30 to 60 seconds. During the freeze, the computer reacts to nothing. After the freeze, the computer complains on a blue background about DPC watchdog violation as shown in

[image: []

Nothing is logged in Windows event logs that would indicate a crash. It is as if the computer simply ceased to do anything at a random point. The random point is not during high use. I can have the computer idling and then it simply stops.

What measures are available for troubleshooting this?

EDIT: On the most recent freeze, I got:

> A corrected hardware error has occurred.
>
> Reported by component: Processor Core Error Source: Corrected Machine
>   Check Error Type: Cache Hierarchy Error Processor APIC ID: 10
>
> The details view of this entry contains further information.

EDIT 2: When running Memtest64, installation of HWMonitor produces error messages and Thunderbird simply crashed. While I am inclined to blame memory, the CPU is also running at a higher speed than I would like (it has a steady 4.7GHz although I am not an overclocker and I have believed I am running it at 3.6GHz). During memory testing, the CPU package temperature is 55 degrees centigrade and individual cores +/- 2 degrees.

EDIT 3: So far the system is stable after running MSI_util_v2.exe (from https://github.com/CHEF-KOCH/MSI-utility/releases) and setting the overlapping Realtek HD Audio interrupts to MSI mode. Both the NVIDIA Geforce 2080 RTX and Realtek HD Audio devices were using interrupt 16.

CONCLUSION: The solution in edit 3 makes the system stable.

Comment: This is a common symptom of either an over-heating CPU or faulty RAM. I'd start monitoring CPU temperatures, maybe even consider re-applying thermal paste or at the very least cleaning out your PC case from dust etc... As for the RAM, a memtest should pick up anything untoward. https://www.techpowerup.com/memtest64/

Comment: Thank you for the insight. The case is rather dust-free and the temperature of the CPU is around 32 degrees centigrade. Will test the memory.

Comment: With respect to memory, you can try removing all modules but one (if you have more than one) and then check each module. Also get memtest86.exe (use Google) and run this for several complete passes to check the memory

Comment: Ideas on how many loops I should run the memtest for? Or how many hours? Note that while running TechPowerUp's MemTest64 v1.0 and simultaneously updating CPUID HWMonitor, I received many memory error messages from the HWMonitor installer.

Comment: After 12 hours of testing with Passmark's Memtest86, two rounds of Memtest64 and one round of Burn-in test from Passmark, nothing found.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, downloading MSI_util_v2.exe (from https://github.com/CHEF-KOCH/MSI-utility/releases), running it as administrator and enabling MSI for either the High Definition Audio Controller (x2) or NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 solved the issue.
[image]